# Кросплатформенная разработка под мобильные

Tags: uwp, xamarin

Как правильно создать приложение для одновременной разработки под Андроид и UWP? Или придется дублировать код под две платформы? Ведь даже библиотеки классов разнятся.

Comment: Можно использовать кроссплатформенные решения наподобие Cordova. Можно использовать какие-либо утилиты, перегоняющие приложение из-под одной платформы в другую. Про что-то такое от Microsoft я когда-то читал. А если приложение на HTML+JS или костыльный перегон с платформы на платформу не радует, то можно написать обёртки для всех платформозависимого функционала, а саму логику приложения без использования языкозависимых конструкций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо использовать Xamarin.Forms. Оно еще и под айос соберет приложение заодно. Всякие кордовы и прочие хтмл-цсс не рекомендую, ибо такие приложения писать не проще, но при этом они намного тормознее и прожорливее.